# How can I add to a value multiple times on an UPDATE with an INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Sorry for the poorly worded question, but I couldn't quite figure out how to phrase it without going into all the following detail.

I have table *t* that has column *value* that I'm trying to update ...

```
mysql> select * from t;
+------+-------+
| k    | value |
+------+-------+
|   10 |  0.00 |
+------+-------+
```

... from table *v*. Table *v* uses *k* as a foreign key ...

```
mysql> select * from v;
+------+-------+
| fk   | value |
+------+-------+
|   10 |  4.00 |
|   10 |  5.00 |
+------+-------+
```

My understanding was that this would be a fairly basic UPDATE with an INNER JOIN, like so:

```
mysql> UPDATE t
    -> INNER JOIN v on v.fk = t.k
    -> SET t.value = t.value + v.value;
```

I was expecting *t.value* to be 9.00, but it comes out as 4.00.

I know I could do it with a subquery and a SUM, but this is going to be running over a massive quantity of data, so I'd prefer to avoid that if at all possible. Is there any way to go about doing this with an inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate the result in a subquery.

```
UPDATE  t
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT fk, SUM(value) totals
            FROM v
            GROUP BY fk
        ) a ON t.k = a.fk
SET     t.value = a.totals
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faac7/1)

Comment: Hrm, that's an interesting one. Will that result in the subquery only being done once?

Comment: Just tested, and it's perfect. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks.